# Document not serving

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, closedxml

I am trying to serve a document when a button is clicked, however the excel sheet is not being downloaded. Nothing happens, no errors or anything, I did wrap it in a try and catch however it doesn't give out any errors, it gets to the `Response.Flush()` and `Response.End()` and nothing happens.

The table used to build the excel sheet it a datatable which is imported from the DB.

I am using ClosedXML

Code

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table = dtResults.Copy();
    table.Merge(dtResultsAll);
    table.TableName = "LookupData";

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(table);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attchment;filename=AuditReport.xlsx");

        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you compare your code to [the according example](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Deliver-an-Excel-file-in-ASP.NET), you'll notice that your header is misspelled: `attchment`vs. `attachment`.

Comment: Iv changed that but its still doing the same thing

Comment: I copied the linked example code and it worked as expected. I changed it to use a DataTable similar to your code and it still worked. I'd recommend you rework your code to resemble the example.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue adding an empty DataTable without any columns. As @astef suggested you seem to swallow the `IndexOutOfRangeException` - take care of this and handle your empty DataTable instead of relying on a lower version of ClosedXML doing this under the covers keeping you wondering about getting an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in ClosedXML.

Downgrade to `0.76.0`.

My repro:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.TableName = "LookupData";
    XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
    wb.Worksheets.Add(table);
    // no exception with below line:
    //wb.Worksheets.Add("table").Cell(1, 1).SetValue("Hello World");
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        wb.SaveAs(memoryStream); // IndexOutOfRangeException here
    }
}
```

Here's my issue: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/493

Comment: I may be nitpicking but that's not exactly reproducing the OP's issue: He doesn't modify cells after adding an empty DataTable. Saving after adding a filled DataTable works as expected in version 0.89.0.0. The OP also stated no exception was thrown.

Comment: Modifying a cell is not necessary (deleted it from answer). About exceptions: I think OP failed catching this exception, since there will be an exception if he uses the version higher than 0.76

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue adding an empty DataTable without any columns.